# Borland C++, problems in getting decimals

Tags: c++, c++builder

I couldn't find a match to what I wanna ask. Why cant I display tan `(39/180*3.142)`?
Instead it gives me `0.0000`, I need the decimals.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    float h, a, d;
    char* number = new char[255];
    a = tan (39/180*3.142);
    sprintf(number, "%.6f", a);
    Height->Text = number;
}
```

Please advice. Thnx.

Comment: What answer did you expect? Are you sure you are using degrees/radians the way you want to?

Comment: Remember to include <float.h>

Comment: Hmm  `Height->Text = number;` is very dangerous name for a component ... because `Height` is also property of your parent window creating naming conflicts ...

Answer (score 3):

try using float numbers, it might calculate 39/180 (integers) as 0:

```
a = tan (39f/180f *3.142);
```

Answer (score 2):

**You are dividing two integers, they will give you zero if the result will be 0.something. So you need to cast one into a float.**

```
(39 / (float)180 * 3.142);
```

Or use float numbers

```
(39.0f / 180.0f * 3.142);
```